# Select most recent value in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2019

I'd like to add the column `LastSalePrice` to the query below:

```
SELECT 
    P.SKU, 
    C.TotalSales,
    MIN(C.MinPriceChannel) OVER(PARTITION BY P.SKU) AS MinPrice,
    MAX(C.MaxPriceChannel) OVER(PARTITION BY P.SKU) AS MaxPrice,
    P.ProductName, 
    C.SalesChannel,
    C.Sales, 
    C.MinPriceChannel, 
    C.MaxPriceChannel
    --C.LastSalePrice
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        P.ProductId
        ,SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY P.ProductId) AS TotalSales
        ,COUNT(*) AS Sales
        ,MIN(OI.UnitPrice) AS MinPriceChannel
        ,MAX(OI.UnitPrice) AS MaxPriceChannel
        ,O.SalesChannel
        --LAST_VALUE(OI.UnitPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY P.ProductId ORDER BY O.SalesDate) as LastSalePrice
    FROM Product P
    JOIN OrderItem OI ON OI.ProductId = P.ProductId
    JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderId = OI.OrderId
    WHERE 
        O.SalesDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY 
        P.ProductId,
        O.SalesChannel
) C
JOIN Product P ON P.ProductId = C.ProductId
ORDER BY P.ProductName ASC, C.SalesChannel ASC
```

I left commented what I have tried - using last_value function - but it says that I can't order by `O.SalesDate` because it's not contained in an aggregation function.

How can I select the last sale price for each product and each sales channel?

Expected output:

| SKU | TotalSales | MinPrice | MaxPrice | ProductName | SalesChannel | Sales | MinPriceChannel | MaxPriceChannel | LastSalePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0002 | 9 | 12.42 | 14.99 | Canned Unicorn Meat | eGulf | 3 | 12.42 | 13.99 | 13.99 |
| 0002 | 9 | 12.42 | 14.99 | Canned Unicorn Meat | Kasim | 3 | 12.72 | 14.95 | 12.72 |
| 0002 | 9 | 12.42 | 14.99 | Canned Unicorn Meat | Nile | 3 | 12.99 | 14.99 | 14.99 |
| 0001 | 9 | 43.99 | 50.00 | StackOverflow Keyboard | eGulf | 3 | 46.60 | 49.75 | 46.60 |
| 0001 | 9 | 43.99 | 50.00 | StackOverflow Keyboard | Kasim | 3 | 43.99 | 50.00 | 48.99 |
| 0001 | 9 | 43.99 | 50.00 | StackOverflow Keyboard | Nile | 3 | 44.99 | 49.99 | 47.99 |

Table definition and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    ProductId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ProductName varchar (255) NOT NULL,
    SKU varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
    OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    SalesDate datetime2 NOT NULL default(GETDATE()),
    SalesChannel varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE OrderItem 
(
    OrderItemId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ProductId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(ProductId),
    OrderId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(OrderId),
    UnitPrice decimal(12, 2) NOT NULL
)

GO
INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, SKU) 
VALUES ('StackOverflow Keyboard', '0001'), 
       ('Canned Unicorn Meat', '0002');
GO

INSERT INTO Orders (SalesDate, SalesChannel) 
VALUES ('2021-04-08', 'Nile'), ('2021-04-09', 'Nile'), ('2021-04-10',  'Nile'),
       ('2021-04-11', 'Nile'), ('2021-04-12', 'Nile'), ('2021-04-13', 'Nile'),
       ('2021-04-08', 'Kasim'), ('2021-04-09', 'Kasim'), ('2021-04-10', 'Kasim'),
       ('2021-04-11', 'Kasim'), ('2021-04-12', 'Kasim'), ('2021-04-13', 'Kasim'),
       ('2021-04-08', 'eGulf'), ('2021-04-09', 'eGulf'), ('2021-04-10', 'eGulf'),
       ('2021-04-11', 'eGulf'), ('2021-04-12', 'eGulf'), ('2021-04-13', 'eGulf');
GO

INSERT INTO OrderItem (ProductId, OrderId, UnitPrice) 
VALUES (1, 1, 49.99), (1, 2, 44.99), (1, 3, 47.99),
       (2, 4, 12.99), (2, 5, 13.99), (2, 6, 14.99),
       (1, 7, 43.99), (1, 8, 50.00), (1, 9, 48.99),
       (2, 10, 14.95), (2, 11, 13.50), (2, 12, 12.72),
       (1, 13, 47.89), (1, 14, 49.75), (1, 15, 46.60),
       (2, 16, 12.42), (2, 17, 13.59), (2, 18, 13.99);
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `FIRST_VALUE`, `LAST VALUE` didn't work for me.

```
;WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT 
        OI.ProductId
        ,OI.UnitPrice
        ,O.SalesChannel
        ,O.SalesDate
        ,FIRST_VALUE(UnitPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY OI.ProductId, SalesChannel ORDER BY O.SalesDate DESC) as LastSalePrice
    FROM OrderItem OI
    JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderId = OI.OrderId
    WHERE 
        O.SalesDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
)
SELECT 
    P.SKU, 
    C.TotalSales,
    MIN(C.MinPriceChannel) OVER(PARTITION BY P.SKU) AS MinPrice,
    MAX(C.MaxPriceChannel) OVER(PARTITION BY P.SKU) AS MaxPrice,
    P.ProductName, 
    C.SalesChannel,
    C.Sales, 
    C.MinPriceChannel, 
    C.MaxPriceChannel,
    C.LastSalePrice
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ProductId
        ,SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId) AS TotalSales
        ,COUNT(*) AS Sales
        ,MIN(UnitPrice) AS MinPriceChannel
        ,MAX(UnitPrice) AS MaxPriceChannel
        ,SalesChannel
        ,MAX(LastSalePrice) AS LastSalePrice
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY 
        ProductId,
        SalesChannel
) C
JOIN Product P ON P.ProductId = C.ProductId
ORDER BY P.ProductName ASC, C.SalesChannel ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a scalar subquery

```
WITH src AS(
    SELECT OI.*, O.SalesDate, O.SalesChannel
    FROM OrderItem OI 
    JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderId = OI.OrderId
    WHERE 
        O.SalesDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
)
SELECT 
    P.SKU, 
    C.TotalSales,
    MIN(C.MinPriceChannel) OVER(PARTITION BY P.SKU) AS MinPrice,
    MAX(C.MaxPriceChannel) OVER(PARTITION BY P.SKU) AS MaxPrice,
    P.ProductName, 
    C.SalesChannel,
    C.Sales, 
    C.MinPriceChannel, 
    C.MaxPriceChannel,
    C.LastSalePrice
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        P.ProductId
        ,SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY P.ProductId) AS TotalSales
        ,COUNT(*) AS Sales
        ,MIN(OOI.UnitPrice) AS MinPriceChannel
        ,MAX(OOI.UnitPrice) AS MaxPriceChannel
        ,OOI.SalesChannel
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 z.UnitPrice
           FROM src z 
           WHERE P.ProductId = z.ProductId AND OOI.SalesChannel = z.SalesChannel
           ORDER BY z.SalesDate DESC) as LastSalePrice
    FROM Product P
    JOIN src OOI ON OOI.ProductId = P.ProductId
    GROUP BY 
        P.ProductId,
        OOI.SalesChannel
) C
JOIN Product P ON P.ProductId = C.ProductId
ORDER BY P.ProductName ASC, C.SalesChannel ASC
```